# Как интегрировать модуль multiprocessing в этот код

Tags: python, многопоточность, tkinter, multiprocessing

При увеличении количества точек, или максимальной длинны соединения программа начинает подтормаживать, подскажите как корректно интегрировать в данный код модуль multyprocessing, я хочу использовать параллельные процессы в функции def lines() для оптимизации работы двухуровневого цикла for. А конкретно вычислять верхний уровень for с помощью мульти-процессов.

Заранее спасибо!

```
import tkinter as tk                    #Нужен для визуального оформления программы
import ctypes                           #Нужен для получения размеров монитора
import random                           
import math                             

inf             = ctypes.windll.user32          #Получаем все сведенья о системе
width           = inf.GetSystemMetrics(0)       #Получаем ширину экрана
height          = inf.GetSystemMetrics(1)       #Получаем высоту экрана
particles       = []                            #Массив для хранения всех чатиц, т.е. объектов класса Particle
mode            = 'b'                           #Это тип цветовой палитры, понажимайте на клавиатуре 'r', 'g', 'b', 'w', 'o', 'd', последнее рекомендуется нажать пару раз
colors          = ''                            #Этот параметр нужен для работы цветовой палитры  mode == 'd'
cnf             = {                             #Список параметров
    'bgcolor'         : 'black',                #Цвет фона
    'particlecolor'   : 'blue',                 #Цвет частицы
    'particleradiuse' : 3,                      #Радиус частицы
    'particalcount'   : 40,                     #Количество частиц
    'particalspeed'   : 5,                      #Максимальная скорость частицы
    'linelenght'      : 200,                    #Радиус, в пределах которого строится соединени данной точки с другой 
    'brightness'      : 90                      #Это параметр отвечает за яркость линий соединений, чем выше, тем бледнее линии соединений
}

root = tk.Tk()                                  
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)            #При запуске програмы сразу             открываем окно на полный экран

c1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 100, height = 1000, bg = cnf['bgcolor'],highlightthickness = 0, cursor= 'None')    #Создаем Canvas, размеры потом поменяются
c1.focus_set()                          #Делаем наше окно активным
c1.pack(fill = 'both', expand = 1)      #Растягиваем Canvas на весь экран

class Particle():
    '''Класс создания частиц, и редактирования их свойств'''
    def __init__(self):
        '''Задаем произвольную позицию'''
        self.x = random.randint(cnf['particleradiuse'], width -cnf['particleradiuse']) 
        self.y = random.randint(cnf['particleradiuse'], height -cnf['particleradiuse'])
        '''Задаем произвольную скорость в +- диапозоне от максимальной'''
        self.xspeed = random.random()*cnf['particalspeed']*2-cnf['particalspeed']
        self.yspeed = random.random()*cnf['particalspeed']*2-cnf['particalspeed']

    def position(self):
        '''Изменяем позицию частицы, учитывая собственную скорость и столкновение с краем экрана'''
        if self.x+self.xspeed+cnf['particleradiuse'] >= width or self.x+self.xspeed-cnf['particleradiuse'] <= 0:
            self.xspeed *= -1       #При привышении границ экрана менять горизонтальную скорость на противоположную
        if self.y+self.yspeed+cnf['particleradiuse'] >= height or self.y+self.yspeed-cnf['particleradiuse'] <= 0:
            self.yspeed *= -1       #При привышении границ экрана менять вертикальную скорость на противоположную
        '''Меняем координаты прибавив скорость'''
        self.x += self.xspeed
        self.y += self.yspeed

    def coords(self, axis):
        '''Метод возвращает координаты точки'''
        if axis == 'x':
            return self.x
        else:
            return self.y

    def redraw(self):   
        '''Функция отрисовки частицы'''
        try:
            self.circle = c1.create_oval(self.x-cnf['particleradiuse'], self.y-cnf['particleradiuse'], self.x+cnf['particleradiuse'], self.y+cnf['particleradiuse'], fill = cnf['particlecolor'], width = 1)
        except:
            pass

def redrawParticles():
    '''Основная функция'''
    while True:
        try:
            '''Перехватываем нажатия с клавиатуры для изменения цветовой палитры или завершения программы'''
            c1.bind("<r>", lambda event: changemode('r'))       #красная тема
            c1.bind("<g>", lambda event: changemode('g'))       #зеленая
            c1.bind("<b>", lambda event: changemode('b'))       #синяя
            c1.bind("<w>", lambda event: changemode('w'))       #серая
            c1.bind("<d>", lambda event: changemode('d'))       #все линии одного случайного цета
            c1.bind("<o>", lambda event: changemode('o'))       #каждая линия случайного цвета
            c1.bind("<Escape>", lambda event: root.destroy())   #Завершение программы
        except:
            '''Если root.destroy то программа завершается'''
            break
        try:
            '''Отчицаем Canvas для следующего кадра'''
            c1.delete('all')
        except:
            pass
        for i in range(cnf['particalcount']):
            '''Для каждой частицы рассчитываем новое положение и отрисовываем частицу там'''
            particles[i].position()
            particles[i].redraw()
        lines()         #Рисуем соединения между частиц
        root.update()   #Обновляем root для отображения результата

def changemode(new_mode):
    global mode, colors
    '''Меняем цвет для режима d'''
    colors = '#'+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9)) 
    mode   = new_mode   #Изменяем текущую цветовую тему на новую

def color(length):
    '''Яркость линии зависит от расстояния, чем ближе тем ярче'''
    if mode == 'r' or mode == 'g' or mode == 'b' or mode == 'w':    
        '''Если значение цвета зависит только от одного показателя RGB или является монохромным то выполняем рассчет яреости линии соединениея'''           
        color = cnf['linelenght']-int(round(length/cnf['linelenght'], 2)*100)-cnf['brightness']
        if color >= 100:
            color = 99
        if color <= 0:
            color = 0
        if color < 10:
            color = '0'+str(color)
        else:
            color = str(color)

        if mode == 'r':
            cnf.update({'particlecolor': 'red'})
            return '#'+color+'0000'
        elif mode == 'g':
            cnf.update({'particlecolor': 'green'})
            return '#'+'00'+color+'00'
        elif mode == 'b':
            cnf.update({'particlecolor': 'blue'})
            return '#'+'0000'+color
        elif mode == 'w':
            cnf.update({'particlecolor': 'grey'})
            return '#'+color+color+color

    elif mode == 'o':
        #Случайный цвет каждой линии по отдельности
        cnf.update({'particlecolor': 'purple'})
        return '#'+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))+str(random.randint(0, 9))
    else:
        #Случайный цвет для всех линий одинаковый
        cnf.update({'particlecolor': 'purple'})
        return colors

def lines():
    '''Проверяем дистанцию до каждой из точек'''
    for i in particles:
        for j in particles:
            x1 = i.coords('x')      #Координаты первой точки
            y1 = i.coords('y')
            x2 = j.coords('x')      #Координаты второй точки
            y2 = j.coords('y')
            length = math.sqrt(math.pow((x2-x1),2) + math.pow((y2-y1), 2))              
            #Нахом расстояние между двумя точками
            if length < cnf['linelenght']:                                                  
            #Если расстояние меньше максимальной длянны линиии, то строим соединение
                try:
                    '''Рисуем линию соединения, а цвет возьмем из функции для этого'''
                    c1.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, width = 2, fill = color(length))
                except:
                    pass

def start():
    for i in range(cnf['particalcount']):
        '''Наполняем массив частицами с произвольными скорость, положением, направлением'''
        particles.append(Particle())
    redrawParticles()       #Вызываем функцию отрисовки

start()         #Вызываем функцию для запуска программы

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: **Никогда, НИКОГДА не прикрепляйте код и вообще какую-либо информацию по ссылке!!!** Перенесите Ваш код непосредственно в вопрос! Вопросы на SO хранятся очень долго и, когда лет через 5 кто-то загуглит такой же вопрос и перейдёт сюда, ссылка может стать уже недействительной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ну как бы да. наверное будет примерно так. за правильность кода не ручаюсь, на питоне пишут редко. может где ошибся. но распараллелить можно как-то в этом ключе.

```
def calc_distance(index, particles, minlen):
    x1 = particles[index].coords('x')  # Координаты первой точки
    y1 = particles[index].coords('y')
    result = []
    for j in range(index+1, len(particles)):
        x2 = particles[j].coords('x')  # Координаты второй точки
        y2 = particles[j].coords('y')
        length = math.sqrt(math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + math.pow((y2 - y1), 2))  # Нахом расстояние между двумя точками
        result.append((x1, y1, x2, y2, length, length > minlen))
    return result


def calc_distances(particles):
    import multiprocessing
    results = None
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(lambda particle: calc_distance(particle, particles, cnf['linelenght']), range(len(particles) - 1))
    return results


def lines():
    for level1 in calc_distances(particles):
        for level2 in level1:
            x1, y1, x2, y2, length, ok = level2
            if ok:
                try:
                    '''Рисуем линию соединения, а цвет возьмем из функции для этого'''
                    c1.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, width = 2, fill = color(length))
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: с одной стороны в питоне очень удобно сделано много, с другой более менее сложное приложение нужно дробить на куски с multiprocessing'ом из-за того, что потоки из-за GIL'а в одном процессе одновременно работать не могут :(

Answer (score 0):

Так, сразу навскидку пара замечаний:

1. Сделайте для `x` и `y` отдельные свойства, через которые можно сразу их получить по отдельности, ведь работа со строками - медленная, вы сами замедляете зачем-то свою программу, делая лишнее сравнение со строкой `if axis == 'x':`
2. Вы фактически два раза пересчитываете расстояние и рисуете одно и то же: сначала от точки `A` до точки `B`, а потом наоборот от `B` до `A`, да и линию от `A` до `A` вы тоже зачем-то рисуете.

Надо сделать примерно так:

```
for i in range(len(particles) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(particles)):
        p1 = particles[i]
        p2 = particles[j]
        ...
```

С вычислением цвета у вас тоже явно много излишества, но я пока не разбирался ещё толком.

А вообще матрицу расстояний ещё лучше вычислять с помощью специальных функций, например [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), это будет гораздо быстрее, чем на чистом питоне.